# Inspection 'Incorrect call arguments' options in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, aiogram

I tried to add keyboard buttons in the Telegram bot Using the Python Aiogram Framework. But there is an error 'Inspection 'Incorrect call arguments' options' in pycharm.

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import *
from aiogram import *
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

# Defining and adding buttons
button1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="button1", callback_data="In_First_button")
button2 = InlineKeyboardButton(
    text="button2", callback_data="In_Second_button")
keyboard_inline = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(button1, button2)

# commands
async def start_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text('Hello there! I\'m a bot. What\'s up?',reply_markup=keyboard_inline)

async def check_button(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    # Checking which button is pressed and respond accordingly
    if call.data == "In_First_button":
        await call.message.answer("Hi! This is the first inline keyboard button.")
    if call.data == "In_Second_button":
        await call.message.answer("Hi! This is the second inline keyboard button.")
    # Notify the Telegram server that the callback query is answered successfully
    await call.answer()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()

    # commands
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_command))
    app.callback_query_handler(text=["In_First_button", "In_Second_button"])

    # polling
    app.run_polling(poll_interval=2)
```

Output:

```
keyboard_inline = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(button1, button2)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\___\main.py", line 165, in __init__
    __pydantic_self__.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(data, self_instance=__pydantic_self__)
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for InlineKeyboardMarkup
inline_keyboard
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={}, input_type=dict]
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code? If a red inspection is on code which works it usually indicates that the python-sdk is misconfigured. If the code does not run than it probably has nothing to do with pycharm.

Comment: why are you using two libraries at the same time

Comment: Try removing the `from aiogram import *` statement and run the code again